# Grouping work hours for consecutive days

Tags: python, parsing, datetime

#### Problem Description

The problem was initially posted here: [Parse and clean up text block of store hours in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46106455/771848).

Given the following multi-line string:

```
"""Hours
Monday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Tuesday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Wednesday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Thursday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Friday 9:30 AM - 11:00 PM
Saturday 9:30 AM - 11:00 PM
Sunday 11:00 AM - 6:00 PM
Holiday Hours
Thanksgiving Day 11:00 AM - 6:00 PM"""
```

Group the consecutive weekdays by the work hours, producing the following output:

```
"""Mon-Thu 9:30AM-9:00PM  
Fri-Sat 9:30AM-11:00PM
Sun & Hol 11:00AM-6:00PM"""
```

#### Solution

My approach is based on parsing the weekday lines, splitting by the first space and then using `itertools.groupby()` to sort by the second item of every row, using the `groupby`'s implementation detail - it would only group the consecutive matches together:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter


data = """Hours
Monday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Tuesday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Wednesday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Thursday 9:30 AM - 9:00 PM
Friday 9:30 AM - 11:00 PM
Saturday 9:30 AM - 11:00 PM
Sunday 11:00 AM - 6:00 PM
Holiday Hours
Thanksgiving Day 11:00 AM - 6:00 PM"""

# filter relevant rows with weekdays only
rows = [row.split(" ", 1) for row in data.splitlines()[1:-2]]

# group consecutive days by a time range
result = []
for time_range, group in groupby(rows, key=itemgetter(1)):
    days_in_group = [item[0] for item in group]

    first_day, last_day = days_in_group[0][:3], days_in_group[-1][:3]
    range_end = "-" + str(last_day) if first_day != last_day else ""

    result.append("{begin}{end} {time_range}".format(begin=first_day,
                                                     end=range_end,
                                                     time_range=time_range))

print("\n".join(result))
```

Is this the most optimal solution to the problem? Is it Pythonic? What would you improve code quality-wise?

Comment: The `& Hol` part of the output is difficult to infer programmatically, and in fact, you haven't done it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obtaining `& Hol` in the output is quite difficult to achieve programmatically in any reasonable way, without hard-coding special cases.  I see that you have not attempted to satisfy that part of the request.  So, the specification is open to interpretation.  I would say that a reasonable approach is to try to parse the opening hours if the line looks like a day of the week, and pass through the output if the line contains anything else.

For the parsing, I would use regular expressions.  If you use named capture groups, you can avoid mysterious expressions like `.split()`, `itemgetter(1)`, and `days_in_group[0][:3]`.

Instead of `.append()`, I'd write it as a generator function.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
import re

def group_by_hours(s):
    REGEX = re.compile(r'^(?P<day_abbrev>\w{3})\w*day (?P<hours>.* - .*)|'
                       r'^(?P<misc>.*)', re.MULTILINE)
    for hours, lines in groupby(REGEX.finditer(s), itemgetter('hours')):
        lines = list(lines)
        if not hours:
            for line in lines:
                yield line['misc']
        elif len(lines) == 1:
            yield "{0} {1}".format(lines[0]['day_abbrev'], hours)
        elif len(lines) > 1:
            yield "{0}-{1} {2}".format(lines[0]['day_abbrev'],
                                       lines[-1]['day_abbrev'],
                                       hours)

print('\n'.join(group_by_hours(data)))
```

Comment: I particularly like using the named groups for both the days and abbreviated days, switching to a generator and, of course, overall, handling the other parts of the data string. Thanks, learned new ways of thinking about the code.

Answer (score 3):

## magic numbers

In

```
rows = [row.split(" ", 1) for row in data.splitlines()[1:-2]]
```

the 1 & -2 magic numbers are a bit of a wart. Perhaps you'd like to create a generator that knows to suppress 'Hours' and that won't yield any further lines after 'Holiday Hours'.

Also,

```
first_day, last_day = days_in_group[0][:3], days_in_group[-1][:3]
```

has some magic numbers, but arguably they make more sense. You could make your generator responsible for day parsing, with `yield day[:3], time_range`.

## variable renaming

In your string formatting, you choose to rename first_day to begin, and range_end to end. I suppose my advice is "don't do that". Or if there's a name you prefer for those variables, use that consistently throughout.

In

```
days_in_group = [item[0] for item in group]
```

the identifier `item` is a bit vague. `pair` would be better (or perhaps `day_range` if you lean toward the verbose).

## global scope

You polluted the top-level namespace with `rows` and other identifiers. Your file cannot be reused via `import`. Please use the

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

idiom to bury these lines of code under `def main():` or similar.

Overall, yes, this is sensible code, put together in pythonic fashion.